# Call to a member function where() on array laravel 5.0.35

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I`m use

```
    public function getImages($array_symbols_id){

    $array_images  = DB::table('photo')
        ->whereIn('photo_symbol_id', $array_symbols_id)
        ->where('photo_moderation_id','2')
        ->orderByRaw('RAND()')
        ->get(['photo_id', 'photo_src', 'photo_symbol_id']);
```

then try

```
        $array = array();

    foreach ($array_symbols_id as $id) {
        $array[] = $array_images->where('photo_symbol_id', $id)->first()->photo_src;
    }
```

but i have exception Call to a member function where() on array.

Why DB::table returns an array but not a collection?

laravel v5.0.35

Comment: The problem is not with DB::table, but with this line I believe `$array_images->where('photo_symbol_id', $id)`. Somewhere you might be converting the collection to an array....

Answer (score 7):

In Laravel 5.0, DB returns an array and Model returns collections, so you can make it a collection by using `collect()`:

```
$array_images = collect(DB::table('photo')
        ->whereIn('photo_symbol_id', $array_symbols_id)
        ->where('photo_moderation_id','2')
        ->orderByRaw('RAND()')
        ->get(['photo_id', 'photo_src', 'photo_symbol_id']));
```